# pfSense 2.4.2 HTTPS and SSH unresponsive

Tags: networking, linux-networking, pfsense

My pfSense 2.4.2 install is unresponsive to HTTPS and SSH, though I am sure my WAN and LAN configurations are correct. My Network Map shows the current configuration, but from both the server and desktop I can not access the VM.

[image: Network Map]

The server's IP is `192.168.1.100` and the desktop's IP is `192.168.1.250`, while the pfSense is `192.168.1.150`. I can not connect to the pfSense router to do any configuration, and the only settings I have changed are the WAN and LAN!

I would also like to note that pfSense is able to ping 192.168.1.1, my external router that exits to the internet. I am installing pfSense to monitor and check traffic coming from the virtual machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was I tried placing the WAN and LAN on the 192.168.1.* range causing a mixup when traffic hit the pfSense router.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are trying to connect to pfSense's WAN interface, but pfSense has port 22, 80 and 443 open only to LAN, so you of course cannot login to admin interface this way. you could connect to it from your VM #{1,2}, but they are probably behind NAT (you didn't specified this so I'm only guessing) so you are again *of course* forbidden to access it. if I'm wrong, try to edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: Just tried on a VM in the LAN to access the pfSense's IP (192.168.1.1), but it too failed.

Comment: @SeanMitchell try restarting your pfSense if possible - it could be a software or hardware failure. you can also attach a display to this device to see what's going on. if problem persists, try to check firewall settings locally.

Comment: I have tried restarting it. What firewall settings should I check?

Comment: you should check if port 22 and 80/443 are permitted on your LAN/WAN interface... and check routes as well; you can also paste output of `pfctl -sa` command here (edit your question and add it).